# SQL Server Recursion query

Tags: recursive-query

Hi I have the following Node and Link tables. I need to build the line coordinates array using the Node table. However if the type of node is a vertex, I need to add the coordinates to the array and get the next coordinates (using FromID->ToID) until a non vertex is found, which is the end point of the line.
I have tried to follow a solution using recursive queries from previous posts, but this didn't work. Is Recursive queries or querying an XML (by joining the 2 tables) output the best way to achieve this? I am using SQL Server 2008

Node Table:

```
NODEID  TYPE  COORDS

BEND1   VALVE   (439754,350240)
BEND3   VALVE   (439720,350268)
COP1    HYDRANT (439879,350292)
EFJ1    FITTING (439740,350248)
NFH1    VALVE   (439798,350262)
NFH2    VALVE   (439802,350313)
NWO3    VALVE   (439752,350244)
NSV1    VALVE   (439877,350292)
NSV2    VALVE   (439753,350245)
NSV3    VALVE   (439752,350244)
TP1     HYDRANT (439752,350244)
TP2     HYDRANT (439864,350360)
VERTEX3 VERTEX  (439805,350314)
VERTEX1 VERTEX  (439730,350286)
VERTEX2 VERTEX  (439769,350301)
PR4     VALVE   (439824,350332)
VERTEX6 VERTEX  (439853,350357)
```

LINK TABLE

```
FROMID  TOID   STATUS    
BEND1   NWO3    OPER    
BEND3   VERTEX1 OPER    
COP1    NSV1    OPER    
EFJ1    BEND3   OPER    
NFH1    NSV1    OPER    
NFH2    VERTEX3 OPER    
TP1     NSV3    OPER    
VERTEX1 VERTEX2 OPER    
VERTEX2 NFH2    OPER    
VERTEX3 PR4 OPER
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
RECNUM      FROMID    TOID     LINE_COORDS
1           BEND1     NWO3     (439754,350240),(439752,350244)
2           BEND3     NFH2     (439720,350268),(439730,350286),(439769,350301),(439802,350313)
3           COP1      NSV1     (439879,350292),(439877,350292)
4           EFJ1      BEND3     (439740,350248),(439720,350268)
5           NFH1      NSV1     (439798,350262),(439877,350292)
6           NFH2      PR4     (439802,350313),(439805,350314),(439824,350332)
7           TP1       NSV3     (439752,350244),(439752,350244)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this but I have no SQL Server on the hand to test the query.

```
WITH PathCTE as
(
    select
        X1.FromID as FromID,
        X1.ToID as ToID,
        [Path] = cast(N1.Coords + ',' + N2.Coords as nvarchar(max)),
        Stop = (case when N2.TYPE = 'VERTEX' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
    from
        tblLink X1 inner join tblNode N1 on X1.FromID = N1.NodeID
                   inner join tblNode N2 on X1.ToID = N2.NodeID
    where
        not exists (select 1 from tblLink X2 where X2.ToID = X1.FromID AND N1.TYPE = 'VERTEX')

    union all

    select
        PathCTE.FromID,
        X.ToID,
        [Path] =  PathCTE.[Path] + ',' + tblNode.Coords,
        STOP = (case when tblNode.TYPE = 'VERTEX' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
    from
        PathCTE
        inner join tblLink X on PathCTE.ToID = X.FromID
        inner join tblNode on X.ToID = tblNode.NodeID
    where PathCTE.Stop = 0
)

select RecNUM = row_number() over (order by FromID), FromID, ToID, Path as Line_Coords
from 
    PathCTE 
where
    PathCTE.Stop = 1
order by
    FromID;
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is what I am getting as output:                               <pre>                                                                                             RecNUM FromID Path
1 BEND1 (439754,350240),(439752,350244
2 COP1 (439879,350292),(439877,350292
3 COP1 (439879,350292),(439877,350292
4 EFJ1 (439740,350248),(439720,350268
5 NFH1 (439798,350262),(439877,350292
6 NFH1 (439798,350262),(439877,350292
7 TP1 (439752,350244),(439752,350244                                  </pre>

Comment: Unfortunately the query doesn't work. I don't get the coordinates of the vertices

Comment: You're right, I've corrected and test this new query.

Comment: Thanks. This is quite useful, however does not give the expected output. The path for any link should stop where TYPE of node is not 'VERTEX'. Your code is giving one link all the way from EFJ1 to PR4. See above for output I am expecting

Comment: New try. Could you check ?

Comment: Still doesn't work.. Output contains only 1 record :                                                                                                             1  VERTEX1 NFH2 (439730,350286),(439802,350313)

Comment: And now ? An other try please.